# How do I enable or disable Windows Firewall rules using the command prompt?

Tags: windows-10, windows-firewall

I have some rules that I want to be toggled on and off. In Windows 10, how do I enable/disable these rules using the cmd prompt?

Answer (score 8):

Run this in an elevated CMD (replace name with the name of your rule)

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="TestRule" new enable=yes
```

To disable the rule again run

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="TestRule" new enable=no
```